# fgets and strlen in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, fgets

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

main()
{
    char str[5]={'\0'};
    printf("Initial length before passing = %ld\n",strlen(str));
    input(str);
    printf("Received string = %s\n",str);
    printf("Length after getting input(calling function) = %ld\n",sizeof(str));
}

input(char * buffer)
{
    puts("Enter something: ");
    printf("Initial length after passing = %ld\n",strlen(buffer));

    if ( fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) == NULL )
        return -1;
    else
    {
        printf("Length after getting input(called function)= %ld\n",strlen(buffer));
        return 0;
    }
}
```

#### Output 1

```
Initial length before passing = 0
Enter something: 
Initial length after passing = 0
hello
Length after getting input(called function)= 6
Received string = hello

Length after getting input(calling function) = 5
```

#### Output 2

```
Initial length before passing = 0
Enter something: 
Initial length after passing = 0
helloooooo
Length after getting input(called function)= 7
Received string = hellooo
Length after getting input(calling function) = 5
```

Why is it printing different lengths in when I gave different input?

1. In output 1 & 2 why the initial length is 6 when I allocated space for only 5 characters?
2. Why is the length of string different before passing and after passing in both output 1 and output 2?
3. In output 2 why "Length after getting input(called function)= 7" when I allocated only less space?

Comment: You must be running a 64-bit compilation.  If you weren't, `sizeof(buffer)` in `input()` would be 4, and you'd see the string `hel` for both input sequences.  You must pass the size of the array explicity to a function: `extern int input(char *buffer, size_t buflen);` and then inside the function refer to `buflen` instead of `sizeof(buffer)`.  The rest is basically invoking undefined behaviour; you get what you get and there's no grounds for complaint since you overflowed your array.  C does not protect you from yourself or your ignorance; it is a harsh language (but powerful and fun too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*1) In output 1 & 2 why the initial length is 6 when i allocated space for only 5 characters?*

Your first `strlen(str)` call isn't really even defined since you declared `char str[5]` but didn't put anything into it. So the contents are who-knows-what. That fact that `strlen(str)` returned a 6 just means that there happened to be 6 non-zero characters in memory, starting at address `str` before it encountered a 0.

*2) why the length of string is different before passing and after passing in both output 1 and output 2?*

After getting a length of 6 for random memory contents, you loaded something into the string buffer and zero terminated it. So the length changed to something real.

*3) In output 2 why "Length after getting input(called function)= 7" when i allocated only less space?*

Because you actually overran your allocated space with a longer string (of length 7). You were lucky the program didn't crash in that case.

When you declare a buffer in C, such as:

```
char str[5];
```

All it does is tell the compiler you're reserving 5 bytes of space to do something and it entitles you to use that space and only that space for `str`. It doesn't necessarily have anything in the buffer to start unless you put something there, and it doesn't prevent you from writing more than you declared.

Note that `str[5]` isn't big enough to hold "hello" since strings in C are zero-terminated. So you need a character buffer of size N+1 to hold a string of size N. When you overflow buffers in C, your results will become erratic and unpredictable.

Comment: Thanks. In output 1 i gave only 5 character input. But why the length is 6 before returning and how it is changed to 55 after returning?

Comment: @user1762571 There are several problems in the code which are causing some undefined behavior. You're passing sizeof(buffer) to fgets and sizeof(buffer) will be the size of a character pointer in memory, not the size of the buffer. sizeof is the size of the data type, not the length of the contents it points to (if a pointer). I'm not sure how large a pointer is on your system, so I'm not sure what fgets is trying to read. But because of the buffer overflow issue you have with str[5] which won't hold "hello" plus the trailing 0, you can get lots of unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

`strlen` was supposed to be working with C strings, that is, char arrays that ends with `\0`. When you define:

```
char str[5];
```

`str` contains garbage, you are lucky calling `strlen` didn't cause segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> char str[5];
> printf("Initial length before passing = %ld\n",strlen(str));
> ```

`strlen` returns the length of specified string, not the size of the buffer.  You didn't initialize `str` to anything, so it's full of garbage.  `strlen` will return the "length" of that garbage, which could be anything.